# typedef alias for map of map

Tags: c++, dictionary, alias

A really simple question, but I don' find the answer. I want to do this :

`ClassA* a = MapOf_ptrMap[key1][key2];` with MapOf_ptrMap a `map< string , ( map < string, ClassA* >)* >` object.

`MapOf_ptrMap[key1]` returns a pointer toward a `map<string, ClassA*>` object (at this point I want you to know that I didn't design this, just have to cope with it).

I've tried `#define X[Key1][Key2] (*(X[Key1]))[Key2]` but it is not working because of the brackets. I know it works with parenthesis but I rather keep the brackets. Also what bother me is the `define` alias does not take the type of `X` into account : I would like to check the input type with `MapOf_ptrMap` type.

Any idea ?

Comment: I've never seen the `#define` directive used with an equal sign, as if you were making an assignment. Could that be a problem? Probable that I'm just unfamiliar with the syntax, though.

Comment: @acheong87 You've never seen it, because it doesn't work. What the line does is define `X` to textually expand to `[Key1][Key2] = (*(X[Key1]))[Key2]`

Comment: @georgesl Still, even without the `=`, this defines a macro named `X` which expands to `[Key1][Key2] (*(X[Key1]))[Key2]`. In short: steer clear of macros unless no other language construct can help you, and doubly re-consider them even then.

Comment: Would `std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, ClassA*>` work for you? It maps `(std::string , std::string) - > ClassA*`.

Comment: I'm working on a 3000-line source file which use the structure everywhere so I cannot change the type easily. @Angew : I know it's an invalid (an dangerous) define : it was just to show what sort of alias I wanted.

Comment: You can do an inline function for the access: `inline ClassA* getA(std:string key1, std::string key2, MapOf_ptrMap &m) { ... }`. Sprinkle/overload with `const` as necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be blunt, `define` is not a very good way to "define" types.

Use a `typedef` instead.

And for our sanity let's break it down:

```
using namespace std;
typedef map<string, ClassA *> map_value_t;
typedef map<string, map_value_t *> map_t;
```

Version with `std::` qualified types (the way the Spaghetti Monster intended):

```
typedef std::map<std::string, ClassA *> map_value_t;
typedef std::map<std::string, map_value_t *> map_t;
```

Now you should be able to declare an object of type `map_t`.

The problem now is, how do we get stuff out of this wretched structure?

```
map_t &blah; // comes from somewhere else.

map_value_t *submap = blah[i];
ClassA *value = *submap[j];
```

Comment: I'v hovering my mouse over the upvote ... you're not seriously suggesting `using namespace std;` for code that's likely to be in a header file, right?

Comment: No I'm not :) It was merely to be more compatible with his own example.

Comment: haha, I've tried to put the std prefix back : there is at least a thousand call to std::methodes in the file .... Anyway, I changed the structure to a Map of Map (which is a bit easier to handle).